# iOS8 Touch ID & Passcode

Tags: ios7, ios8, keychain, biometrics, touch-id

i using this code in iOS 8 for security and uses touch ID

```
- (IBAction)authenticateButtonTapped{





    LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *authError = nil;
    NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"Authenticate using your finger\r Scan Your Finger Now";
    if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {

        [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                  localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                            reply:^(BOOL succes, NSError *error) {

                                if (succes) {

                                    [self showMessage:@"Authentication is successful" withTitle:@"Success"];
                                    NSLog(@"User authenticated");





                                } else {

                                    switch (error.code) {
                                        case LAErrorAuthenticationFailed:
                                            [self showMessage:@"Authentication is failed" withTitle:@"Error"];
                                            NSLog(@"Authentication Failed");
                                            break;

                                        case LAErrorUserCancel:
                                            [self showMessage:@"You clicked on Cancel" withTitle:@"Error"];
                                            NSLog(@"User pressed Cancel button");
                                            break;

                                        case LAErrorUserFallback:
                                            [self showMessage:@"You clicked on \"Enter Password\"" withTitle:@"Error"];
                                            NSLog(@"User pressed \"Enter Password\"");

                                            [self copyMatchingAsync];
                                            break;

                                        default:
                                            [self showMessage:@"Touch ID is not configured" withTitle:@"Error"];
                                            NSLog(@"Touch ID is not configured");
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    NSLog(@"Authentication Fails");
                                }
                            }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Can not evaluate Touch ID");
        [self showMessage:@"Can not evaluate TouchID" withTitle:@"Error"];

    }







}
```

after for use the passcode system i copy this code from apple example

```
- (void)copyMatchingAsync
{
    NSDictionary *query = @{
                            (__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                            (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: @"SampleService",
                            (__bridge id)kSecReturnData: @YES,
                            (__bridge id)kSecUseOperationPrompt: NSLocalizedString(@"AUTHENTICATE_TO_ACCESS_SERVICE_PASSWORD", nil)
                            };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        CFTypeRef dataTypeRef = NULL;
        NSString *msg;

        OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(query), &dataTypeRef);
        if (status == errSecSuccess)
        {
            NSData *resultData = ( __bridge_transfer NSData *)dataTypeRef;
            NSString * result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"RESULT", nil), result];
        } else {

        }

    });
}

-(void) showMessage:(NSString*)message withTitle:(NSString *)title
{

    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                  message:message
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                                 [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                             }];

    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

its work great and rapid for fingerprint but the passcode system can't show and dosen't work. and i received  "ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND" = "error item not found";

this apple link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html

but i can't good understand

Comment: If it works great, what are asking?  What do you mean you want the passcode system easy to test?

Comment: the passcode system dosen't work and dosen't show

Comment: Does any error prints with NSLog?

Comment: i receive " item not found " , "ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND" = "error item not found";

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you but you can't do that.
You are mixing access control with keychain access, You don't have access to the user passcode.

using SecItemCopyMatching is possible if you added a resource with SecItemAdd using the same attributes (the contents of "query")

Answer (score 0):

"ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND" = "error item not found" show no item in keychain.

I also saw the Apple sample code "KeychainTouchID" as you said above.

iOS8's new feature make the developer can use the iPhone user's passcode & Touch ID for authentication.

You have to "Add Item" firstly, and then call "Query for Item".

If you want more convenient solution, maybe you can use [SmileTouchID](https://github.com/liu044100/SmileTouchID).

It is a library for integrate Touch ID & Passcode to iOS App conveniently that even support for iOS7 and the device that cannot support Touch ID.

You just need a few line of code and get what you want.

```
if ([SmileAuthenticator hasPassword]) {
        [SmileAuthenticator sharedInstance].securityType = INPUT_TOUCHID;
        [[SmileAuthenticator sharedInstance] presentAuthViewController];
    }
```